# QGIS: basemap only in overview not in mapatlas

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I have a map Atlas and a small overview map. In the project I have a basemap and I want that the basemap is only visible in the overview map but not in the individual maps of the Atlas. Is that possible and how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for sure possible. In QGIS you can define various 'Map Themes' (i.e. give a name to a certain layer visibllity setting, in your case "with basemap" or "without basemap"):

[image]

[image]

Then in Print Composer you can select one of your map themes (visiblitities) in each maps properties:

[image]

That way you can have different layer settings in each map (overview etc.)